# Complex Coordinate change

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, complex-numbers

I have a simple question where I must change the coordinates of a system however I am unsure whether I am correct.  I am changing from Cartisian to complex coordinates.  Let's say I only have $x$ and $y$ coordinates.  Would that mean $$ x =iy - z $$ and $$ y = \frac{z - x}{i} $$
With the time derivatives being $$\dot{x} = i\dot{y} - \dot{z} $$ and likewise for y.

I know this may be a stupid question but it is bugging me and I cannot seem to find any documentation to help.

Note: I cannot use polar complex coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing $x=iy-z, y=(z-x)/i$ doesn't help you very much because your goal is to introduce new coordinates and then write $(x,y)$ in terms of these. It's nice to start by writing the map in the other direction, i.e.

$$z=x+iy$$

The complex conjugate is then $\bar{z}=x-iy$. These can be inverted to write $(x,y)$ in terms of $(z,\bar{z})$ as

$$ x = \frac{1}{2}(z+\bar{z}), \qquad  y = -\frac{i}{2}(z - \bar{z}) $$